# HTTP Error 500.0 - ANCM In-Process Handler Load Failure with .NetCore 5

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core-webapi, http-status-code-500

[HTTP Error 500.0 - ANCM In-Process Handler Load Failure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHSQ0.png)

Comment: Hi @Luis Estrella, could you please share your error message instead of picture. Also please share the message in English, no one can understand your picture which is not in English.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.